# Using the head and tail function in R to show only row names?

Tags: r

So I have dataframe of over 7000 observations with 270 variables. I have ordered the dataframe alphabetically by the "row names". I've been asked to display the **first 5 and last 5 row names**. If I use the **head()** or **tail()** function as I normally would it tries to display all the variables of that column. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the  `head` and `tail` on the `row.names` of the dataset instead of the dataset and specify the `n`

```
head(row.names(df1), 5)
tail(row.names(df1), 5)
```